# Install modules in druper which is running as a docker container

Tags: docker, drupal, docker-compose, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I think I need help with Drupal combined with Docker. Kind of my first experience. So finally, I made it working, that the container comes up and I can login and fine. But now I want to install some modules but unfortunately I have issues uploading the file. The error message is:

```
Failed to connect to the server. The server reports the following message: 
Cannot connect to FTP Server, check settings
```

I am not even sure if all required components are installed, but I guess so because it is an official image?!?
This is the composer file I am using:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  drupal:
    image: drupal:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ~/drupal/drupal_modules:/var/www/html/modules
      - ~/drupal/drupal_profiles:/var/www/html/profiles
      - ~/drupal/drupal_themes:/var/www/html/themes
      - ~/drupal/drupal_sites:/var/www/html/sites
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - ~/drupal/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    restart: always

  drupal-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal
      MYSQL_USER: mysql
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysql
    volumes:
      - ~/drupal/db_mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
```

Do you have any suggestions how I can install modules?

Also some other hints are welcomed :)

Thanks

Stephan

Edit:
Ok, I guess the problem is my windows host machine and the ACL:
https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal/issues/29
Unfortunately I am not able to fix it

Edit2:
So I used a docker container volume (Docker volume create --name drupal-data), changed my compose file:

```
services:
  drupal:
    image: drupal:latest
    volumes:
      - app-data:/var/www/html/modules:rw
      - app-data:/var/www/html/profiles:rw
      - app-data:/var/www/html/themes:rw
      - app-data:/var/www/html/sites:rw
volumes:
  app-data:                       
    external:
      name: drupal-data
```

and got it finally running under win10

Answer (score 0):

see edit 2.
Used instead a docker volume container for data under windows 10